# ruby shoes: Preventing a new window from opening

Tags: ruby, shoes

So I have a gui like this:

```
Shoes.app title: "MAIN" do
    class MainPanel
        @myApp

        def initialize(myApp)
            @myApp = myApp
        end

        def alert(message)
            @myApp.app do
                alert message
            end
        end

        def add(text)
            @myApp.app do
                append para "lol"
            end
        end
    end

    stack do
        @currPanel = MainPanel.new(self)
        button "start!" do
            @currPanel.alert("balh")
            @currPanel.add("balh")
        end
    end
end
```

I am just so confused why it just doesn't work. By saying it doesn't work I mean it always opens a new window （updated). So every time it executes something, a new window is generated.... 
I don't understand where I did it wrong. I have tried putting the class declaration outside of shoes.app but it didn't work either.....

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to 'lol's to keep piling up each time the button is pressed and alert is shown. If this is the case, then you just need to make a small change and things will work perfectly:

Change your add method FROM:

```
def add(text)
    @myApp.app do
        append para "lol"
    end
end
```

TO:

```
def add(text)
   @myApp.app do
      append do
        para "lol"
      end
    end
end
```

Let me know if I have not understood your question correctly. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Emmmm... I actually ended up not using the class defined above (MainPanel). However, it seems that whenever I create a new object using the "new" keyword, Shoes automatically generates a new window. AND this new window is the welcome page for the app. Now my app opens a new window when I click "start" because that is when a new GraphLib object is created for the first time. I tested several times and I am pretty sure that Shoes just generates a new window whenever I create a new GraphLib...... Thanks for the help tho :)